# How to set minLength in jquery autocomplete from database in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I want to use jquery autocomplete from database in asp.net. I got it working except the minLength option. As shown in the following code, I tried a few ways but couldn't get minLength option working. Please shed light on this. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="../../../jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../jquery/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").autocomplete({ minLength: 4 });
      $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").autocomplete("option", "minLength", 4); 
      $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").autocomplete("AutocompleteData.ashx");
      });
  </script> 

<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="AutocompleteData" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class AutocompleteData : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string schoolname = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
    string sql = "my query";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                context.Response.Write(reader.GetString(0) + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-parameters-using-jquery-ui-for-autocomplete......... check this out. might be you need to define source with the min-length.

Comment: I did some research and experiment. Now I got a workaround. I found it's interesting. I'd like to share my findings with other developers. See http://bettereducation.com.au/it/yaf_postst2254_Jquery-UI-autocomplete--minLength-or-minChars.aspx.

Comment: +1 for your re-search. Good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that I wasn't using JQuery UI, I was using old JQuery plugin instead.

Now I tried JQuery UI and found minLength works. See details in [this link](https://bettereducation.com.au/forum/it.aspx?g=posts&t=2254).